# Get subscriber by email in ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am trying to get subsciber details using the exacttarget API.
I need to get these details by email address but so far I can only get the details by Subscriber key (Code below).

```
        sfp.Property = "SubscriberKey";
        sfp.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
        sfp.Value = new string[] { "1003608" }; // Subscriber key

        // Create the RetrieveRequest ListSubscriber objects
        RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest();
        rr.ObjectType = "ListSubscriber";
        rr.Properties = new string[] { "ListID", "SubscriberKey", "Status"};
        rr.Filter = sfp;

        status = framework.Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out results);
        Console.WriteLine(status);
        // Iterate over the results
        Console.WriteLine("List Subscriber Details:\tList ID\tSubscriberKey\tStatus");
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
        {
            ListSubscriber ls = (ListSubscriber)results[i];
            Console.WriteLine("List Subscriber Details:\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", ls.ListID, ls.SubscriberKey, ls.Status);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

My problem is that I do not know what property I need to feed in to search by email address. I have tried..

```
        sfp.Property = "CustomerKey";
        sfp.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
        sfp.Value = new string[] { "name@test.co.uk" }; // Subscriber key
```

But this gives the error "Ambigous column name 'CustomerKey'".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Bobby

Comment: Do you have more than one column called customer key?

Comment: It would appear so but I am just calling the API so I don't have any control over it. I would guess I was calling the wrong property but I don't know what other property to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email address doesn't exist in the [**ListSubscriber**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/listsubscriber.htm) object.  You'll need to retrieve the [**Subscriber**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/subscriber.htm) object.

If you need access to the Lists for a Subscriber, it's included in the `Lists[]` property.

Comment: Thank you Adam, Once I changed the objecttype to "Subscriber" I could then use "EmailAddress" as my filter.